# redirection technique to use

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i want to redirect users to my site based on the url they typed into the address bar but i am problems as what to actually do. forgive me if i am not using the right term, i am a newbie.

this an example of what i want to achieve

www.mysite.com (is my site)
www.mysite.com/pizza (is what the user typed)

i want the browser to take the user to www.mysite.com if he types www.mysite.com and redirect the user to www.mysite.com/base/tweek.php?ref=pizza if he types www.mysite.com/pizza.

how do i do this?

Comment: You need to use a router/framework setup, or make your own. Google PHP Router Framework. Slim or Laravel come to mind

Comment: You generally use mod_rewrite... assuming your server is Apache. Want to check out the docs, try it and add to your question if it doesn't work? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Why not use `header()`

Comment: @EisaAdil to use header, one would have to have a file called 'pizza' that matched the request and was interpreted as PHP. That means you'd need a file matching anything the user might type in. Dynamic redirection via mod_rewrite would be a lot less work and more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /base/tweek.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Also make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You must create the .htaccess file in the root directory of the page, and write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /base/tweek.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think (handwritten, not checked :) ).
Hope it helps, if You have any problems, try to read some htaccess tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `header` at the top from your index.php:

```
header('Location: anotherindex.php');
```

Comment: This is not a good idea I think... .htaccess should be used. PHP header should be used for example to cancel post data, or to hard link pages. This isn't that case.

Comment: Ye! I always cancel sessions with that. Greetings (: